# Triggering smart campaign and getting 603

Tags: marketo

I am trying to use Marketo smart campaign to send email data.
What I do is:
1) get or create Lead with addresse email
2) trigger smart campaign I've created with this lead_id and a couple of tokens I created on the folder containing the campaign.

That is, I am sending POST to https://.mktorest.com/rest/v1/campaigns/5826/trigger.json?access_token= with body

```
{
    "input": {
        "leads": [
            {
                "id": 2034349
            }
        ], 
        "tokens": [
            {
                "name": "{{my.subject}}", 
                "value": "subj"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "{{my.message}}", 
                "value": "the text"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I get the response:
{u'errors': [{u'message': u'Access denied', u'code': u'603'}], u'requestId': u'c8f5#14c79fae723', u'success': False}

I was trying token names without "{{" and "}}", without "my." - the same result. The campaign exist and has this ID.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The role of the Marketo API user that you're using needs the "Execute Campaign" permission, and your current user is probably missing that permission. Unfortunately you can't edit the existing role. You'll need to create a new role, check that permission, and possibly also create a new API User.